# How to show object fields instead of references when using assertEquals and the Comparison Failure window

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

When I try to compare two similar lists of the same class of objects using JUnit's `assertEquals` method, I get the option in Intellij:

```
<Click to see difference>
```

The Comparison Failure dialog opens and I see the expected references and actual references. I have properly overridden the equals method because when the two objects have the same fields, the test passes.

Instead of showing the references, is it possible to show the fields of the objects?

This will greatly reduce the time it takes to debug a test case.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Implement `toString()` on `Models.YTPoint` and IntelliJ will be able to display a meaningful 'difference message'.

**Detail**

IntelliJ's 'difference message' is derived from the type's `toString()`. If the type has no `toString()` then IntelliJ will use the object reference.

So, if you define a `toString()` on whatever object these lists contain then IntelliJ will be able to display a meaningful 'difference message'.

Here's an exmaple:

```
@Test
public void showDifferenceMessage() {
    List<Foo> one = Lists.newArrayList(new Foo(1, "me"));
    List<Foo> two = Lists.newArrayList(new Foo(1, "you"));

    Assert.assertEquals(one, two);
}
```

With no implementation of `Foo.toString()` when I run the test IntelliJ displays:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[org.glytching.sandbox.Foo@16f65612]
Actual   :[org.glytching.sandbox.Foo@311d617d]
```

And when I implement `Foo.toString()` and re run that test IntelliJ displays:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :[Foo{id=1, name='me'}]
Actual   :[Foo{id=1, name='you'}]
```

And if I `Click to see difference` IntelliJ displays:

[image]